# The proper way to delete rows from UITableView and update array from NSUserDefaults in Swift / iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

What is the proper way to delete rows from `UITableView` and update array from NSUserDefaults?

In the following example I'm reading an array from `NSUserDefaults`and feeding a `UITableView` with its content, I'm also allowing the user to delete items in the `UITableView` what I'm not sure is when to read and write to `NSUserDefaults` so the table updates as soon as a row is deleted. As you can see I start by reading the array the in the `viewDidLoad` method and re-saving it in the `commitEditingStyle` method. With this method my table is not reloading when a row is deleted.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     // Lets assume that an array already exists in NSUserdefaults.
     // Reading and filling array with content from NSUserDefaults.
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var array:Array = userDefaults.objectForKey("myArrayKey") as? [String] ?? [String]()
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel!.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        array.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
  // Save array to update NSUserDefaults     
 let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
 userDefaults.setObject(array, forKey: "myArrayKey")


 // Should I read from NSUserDefaults here right after saving and then reloadData()?
 }
```

How is this usually handled?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it's correct, but you should only save in user defaults if something has been deleted.

```
if editingStyle == .delete {
    array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(array, forKey: "myArrayKey")
}
```

Reading the array back is not needed and not recommended.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` reuse the cell, you need to specify the identifier in Interface Builder.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Cell", for: indexPath)
```

The data source array must be declared on the top level of the class

```
var array = [String]()
```

then assign the value in `viewDidLoad` and reload the table view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    guard let data = userDefaults.array(forKey: "myArrayKey") as? [String] else {
        return 
    }
    array = data
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!