# Swift3: Error in TableView when deleting cells holding UserDefault values

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, userdefaults

I followed all steps provided here: [The proper way to delete rows from UITableView and update array from NSUserDefaults in Swift / iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625350/the-proper-way-to-delete-rows-from-uitableview-and-update-array-from-nsuserdefau)

However, an error is caused, saying;

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I have created

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
struct Section {
    var sectionName: String!
    var words: [String]!

    init(title: String, word: [String]) {
        self.sectionName = title
        self.words = word

    }
}

var arrayForRows = [String]()

var sections = [Section]()
func getData() -> [String] {
if let data = userDefaultDataSave.stringArray(forKey: "data") {
    return data
}
return []
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self

    guard let data = dataDefaults.stringArray(forKey: "data") else {
        return
    }
    arrayForRows = data as [String]
    tableView.reloadData()

    sections = [
        Section(title: "A", word: []), // 1
        Section(title: "B", word: []), //2
        Section(title: "C", word: []),
        Section(title: "D", word: []),
        Section(title: "E", word: []),
        Section(title: "F", word: []),
        Section(title: "G", word: []),
        Section(title: "H", word: []),
        Section(title: "I", word: []),
        Section(title: "J", word: []),
        Section(title: "K", word: []),
        Section(title: "L", word: []),
        Section(title: "M", word: []),
        Section(title: "N", word: []),
        Section(title: "O", word: []),
        Section(title: "P", word: []),
        Section(title: "Q", word: []),
        Section(title: "R", word: []),
        Section(title: "S", word: []),
        Section(title: "T", word: []),
        Section(title: "U", word: []),
        Section(title: "V", word: []),
        Section(title: "W", word: []),
        Section(title: "X", word: []),
        Section(title: "Y", word: []),
        Section(title: "Z", word: [])
    ]


    let getAlphabetData = getData()

    for a in getAlphabetData {

        if a.hasPrefix("A") || a.hasPrefix("a") {
            if sections[0].sectionName == "A" {
                sections[0].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }

        if a.hasPrefix("B") || a.hasPrefix("b") {
            if sections[1].sectionName == "B" {
                sections[1].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }

        if a.hasPrefix("c") || a.hasPrefix("c") {
            if sections[2].sectionName == "C" {
                sections[2].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("D") || a.hasPrefix("d") {
            if sections[3].sectionName == "D" {
                sections[3].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("E") || a.hasPrefix("e") {
            if sections[4].sectionName == "E" {
                sections[4].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("F") || a.hasPrefix("f") {
            if sections[5].sectionName == "F" {
                sections[5].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("G") || a.hasPrefix("g") {
            if sections[6].sectionName == "G" {
                sections[6].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("H") || a.hasPrefix("h") {
            if sections[7].sectionName == "H" {
                sections[7].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("I") || a.hasPrefix("i") {
            if sections[8].sectionName == "I" {
                sections[8].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("J") || a.hasPrefix("j") {
            if sections[9].sectionName == "J" {
                sections[9].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("K") || a.hasPrefix("k") {
            if sections[10].sectionName == "K" {
                sections[10].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("L") || a.hasPrefix("l") {
            if sections[11].sectionName == "L" {
                sections[11].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("M") || a.hasPrefix("m") {
            if sections[12].sectionName == "M" {
                sections[12].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("N") || a.hasPrefix("n") {
            if sections[13].sectionName == "N" {
                sections[13].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("O") || a.hasPrefix("o") {
            if sections[14].sectionName == "O" {
                sections[14].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("P") || a.hasPrefix("p") {
            if sections[15].sectionName == "P" {
                sections[15].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("Q") || a.hasPrefix("q") {
            if sections[16].sectionName == "Q" {
                sections[16].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("R") || a.hasPrefix("r") {
            if sections[17].sectionName == "R" {
                sections[17].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("S") || a.hasPrefix("s") {
            if sections[18].sectionName == "S" {
                sections[18].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("T") || a.hasPrefix("t") {
            if sections[19].sectionName == "T" {
                sections[19].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("U") || a.hasPrefix("u") {
            if sections[20].sectionName == "U" {
                sections[20].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("V") || a.hasPrefix("v") {
            if sections[21].sectionName == "V" {
                sections[21].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("W") || a.hasPrefix("w") {
            if sections[22].sectionName == "W" {
                sections[22].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("X") || a.hasPrefix("x") {
            if sections[23].sectionName == "X" {
                sections[23].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("Y") || a.hasPrefix("y") {
            if sections[24].sectionName == "Y" {
                sections[24].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
        if a.hasPrefix("Z") || a.hasPrefix("z") {
            if sections[25].sectionName == "Z" {
                sections[25].words.append(a as String)
            }
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    return arrayForRows.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section].sectionName
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    // Cellに値を設定する.
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black

    cell.textLabel!.text = sections[indexPath.section].words[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source

        tableView.beginUpdates()

        arrayForRows.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(arrayForRows, forKey: "data")
        tableView.endUpdates()
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }

}
```

}

From another Controller, values are added into the Section's `words` array, by writing this way;

```
  class InputDataViewController: UIViewController {


 // this function is written inside UITextView in this class. 
 //But I omitted here. 

 func addData(text: String) {

    var data = self.getData()
    data.insert(text as NSString, at: 0)
    dataDefault.set(data, forKey: "data")
}


func getData() -> [String] {
    if let data = dataDefault.stringArray(forKey: "data") {
        return data
    }
    return []
 }

}
```

What is the problem? From the way I see it, I can understand if I did not explicitly write `tableView.reloadData()` or `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`, but I did. What is the reason for causing this error? Could you help me?

Thanks.

**Updated**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return sections[section].words.count
}
```

Also, I found out that if I write this way, it worked. However, the selected one was not deleted from my table view. The first index of word was deleted from my table view regardless of the fact that I chose and deleted a row in a section. The deleted row was in another section.

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        //            removeHistory(index: sections[indexPath.section].words[indexPath.row])

        tableView.beginUpdates()

        let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
        indexSet.add(indexPath.section)


        //let indexSet = sections[indexPath.section].words[indexPath.row] as IndexSet
        //sections.remove(at: indexPath.section)
        sections[indexPath.section].words.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        var data = getData()
        data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        dataDefault.set(data, forKey: "data")
        dataDefault.synchronize()

        //tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        tableView.endUpdates()
        //



    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the data source for the table view **after** the call to `reloadData`? It would help if you included the implementation of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` in your snippet.

Comment: @crizzis please check the update

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that every time you add or delete rows, you keep your data source consistant. In your case you're removing object fron `arrayForRows` but your `numberOfRows` is using a completely different data source: `sections[section].words.count`

So you should either

1. Keep `numberOfRows` as it is and remove from `sections[indexPath.section].words` array
2. Change your `nubmerOfRows` method to return `arrayForRows.count`

Just make your choice what is your dataSource and pick the right option. Since you have multiple sections, you should follow the first suggestion.

**Edit:**

You're getting `index out of bounds` error because it seems you never update your `sections` array. You should fill all those `words` arrays for every section, right? But judging by the code you provided they are always empty.

Basically your implementation should look like this:

1. ViewController A displays a list of sections with words starting from a particular letter in every section
2. ViewController B creates new elements and save them to UserDefaults.
3. VC A should update `sections` array every time in `viewWillAppear` method. Just make a loop through all elements in the array from UserDefaults and put every element into the right `Section` object.
4. Every time a row is deleted in VC A you **must** remove it from a corresponding Section object, otherwise app will crash. Also you should remove the same object from UserDefaults array to keep those changes persistent.

Example for a function to insert a word into your `sections` array:

```
func insert(word: String) {
    guard word.characters.count > 0 else { return }
    let firstLetter = String(describing: word.characters.first).lowercased()
    for var section in sections {
        if section.title.lowercased().hasPrefix(firstLetter) {
            section.words.append(word)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you remove an object or in `numberOfRows`?

Comment: Show your updated code and I will tell you what is the mistake.

Comment: I linked a cell to another TableViewController where the code above is written. And when I clicked the cell, it says the error. I think there must be something wrong going on in another file, I guess. I just want to make UITableVIew alphabetically ordered with sections. They will hold words in each section. Those values are saved with UserDefault and come from UITextView. What approach is good for this to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Yes, exactly. It is basically how my code is written. How do I put every element into the "right" Section object? LIke for a in data { if a.hasPrefix("A") || a.hasPrefix("a") {
                if sections[0].sectionName == "A" {
                    //code here?
                }
            } }

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I still does not understand how my code is working. Like error keeps coming out. So I copied and pasted my code inside two view controllers. Could you please have a look at it. I am so annoyed actually for a week and I am frustrated. I appreciate if you could give me solution. It is going to be a huge thanks. @alexburtnik

Comment: @alexburnik hello. I updated again. It is helpful if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you delete row from table view before deleting data? try to delete object from your array and only then delete row from tableView

```
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    arrayForRows.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(arrayForRows, forKey: "data")
    tableView.endUpdates()
```

Also try to look at your numberOfRowsInSection method. I guess it should return

```
arrayForRows.count
```

Comment: No. It is not working. I tried this too, but failed. I am looking for a solution... I cannot see any problem with my code, but there is a bug...

Comment: @Ryo try to change numberOfRowsInSection the way I suggest. The problem is that you delete data from arrayForRows but your tableView rows count does not depend on this array

Comment: And now it said " Index out of range"

Comment: @Ryo do you have only one section in your tableView?

Comment: no, I have many sectons as you can see in my post. There are 25 or 24 sections. And they contain empty arrays until values are added into their words array